# How to display msgbox if subject contains string

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

The following Outlook macro works perfectly, However, I would like this `MsgBox` to only appear if the Subject is `LIKE 'Fees Due%'` OR Subject is `LIKE' Status Change%'`. Is this possible?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should be*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Subject As String
    Subject = Item.Subject

    If Subject Like "*Fees Due*" Or Subject Like "*Status Change*" Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", _
                   vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, _
                                               "Check Subject") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for going the extra mile to help. This has saved me from many headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use `Like` operator:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Item.Subject Like "Fees Due*" Or Item.Subject Like "Status Change*" Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I added outer `If` ... `End If`, nothing else was changed.